# How to install Apache Wicket plugin for Java IDE Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, wicket, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to install the Apache Wicket framework for a Java web application I must develop. I have the Java IDE version of NetBeans 8.0.2 and have installed the Maven plugin. However, when I create a new project there is no Wicket framework selection as show in the installation instructions (https://wicket.apache.org/start/wicket-7.x.html#download). I also used the manual download procedure and I am getting nowhere. I have search this forum, Google and YouTube for clear instructions understandable to a newbie without success.

I also went to NetBeans and downloaded the Wicket Support plugin, but once it was downloaded, there are no more instructions on what to do with it.

Can someone tell me what I might be missing or point me to a post or other resource that clearly explains how to install and use Apache Wicket 7.x with NetBeans?

I am using Windows 10, Java jdk1.8.0_131, NetBeans 8.0.2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the Wicket Support Plugin after downloading it? http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.3/nb/html/setup_nbenv.htm#CCAFJDJE

Answer (score 0):

There is enough to add dependency to maven .pom file for wicket and jetty or another(to be able to start application)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

Now write your wicket classes in main/java and html in main/webapp. 
To build application:

```
mvn clean install
```

To run application:

```
mvn jetty:run
```